# Wait for a property value of another object in coffeescript Class

Tags: class, constructor, coffeescript

I'm wondering if there a way to pass a value which I receive after constructor and put in in constructor options. The problem is that I also have a value from constructor which I need to pass, so it has dependencies from both sides.

```
class Test
  constructor: (@opt={}) ->
    @opt.width = obj.width
    @opt.color = "#f45

    # obj.width is undefined

    obj = new Obj
      width: 200
      color: @opt.color
```

Or my real example.

```
class Button extends Layer
  constructor: (@opt={}) ->
    super _.defaults @opt,
      width: @btnText.width
      type: "default"

    # btnText.width is undefined

    @btnText = new Text
      width: 200
      type: @opt.type
```

How can I solve this problem and get rid of undefined values? Might be I can use some sort of await and promise? Don't know :-)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. You are routing `opt` into your super ctor and also an additional object where this additional object that has 2 properties (`width` and `type`) where `width` is initialized to an undefined state as `@btnText.width` is not defined yet. But then later your initialize the object `btnText` and also you assign it a static value. Why not simply NOT initialize the object that you give to super ctor or what if you simply assign the first occurance of width a value. eg. 200 like you do later or 0?

Comment: I think promises would be a bad fit for this. If you make some values populate asynchronously via promises, then all code which accesses this value must be able to handle the case where it is undefined or an unresolved promise. Why not declare the `width` in the call to super and reused this below in the `@btnText` constructor?